# How to specify the `--formats` sdist option inside setup.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py, sdist

I try to create a zipped source python package on a linux distribution without specifying the `--formats` option to sdist on the command line (using an existing Jenkins pipeline which do not support this option).
In the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html), it states:

> (assuming you haven’t specified any sdist options in the setup script or config file), sdist creates the archive of the default format for the current platform. The default format is a gzip’ed tar file (.tar.gz) on Unix, and ZIP file on Windows.

But it doesn't say how should you specify sdist options in the setup script?

Comment: Are you really using distutils and Python2? The current standards are setuptools and Python3...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, unfortunately, I'm stuck using python2... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the linked documentation [previous topic](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/configfile.html):

> The basic syntax of the configuration file is simple:
>
> ```
> [command]
> option=value
> ...
> ```
>
> where command is one of the Distutils commands (e.g. build_py, install), and option is one of the options that command supports

and later an example for `build_ext --inplace`

> ```
> [build_ext]
> inplace=1
> ```

That means that you must write into the `setup.cfg` file:

```
[sdist]
formats=zip
```

Beware: untested because I have no available Python2...

Comment: Sorry for being lazy on this one and thank you for your help. Reading the documentation I get a sense that this should be doable inside the `setup.py` but having a config file is probably cleaner.